# How is it determined which explanation is simpler?

Tags: epistemology, occams-razor, abduction

One of the criteria of IBE is simplicity.

How to determine which explanation is simpler if there are two types of simplicity:
one type counts the number of hearings, and the other type counts the number of explanations.

If one explanation has fewer entities and the other explanation has fewer explanations, which is simpler?

I cannot understand who should decide this.

Comment: Simplicity can't be that COMPLEX! Do you see the oxymoron? Those criteria are arbitrary and biased (depend on subjectivity). Worst even, what happens when both compete (one explanation has fewer entities and the other has fewer explanations)? Given that subjectivity is unavoidable, you can just use this: simple means _easy to understand_, easiness being subjective (what is simple for you could be complex for me). _Simple simplicity seems better than complex simplicity_.

Comment: How about solipsism? Solipsism has fewer essences but more explanation. The existence of other minds has fewer explanations but more essences. Which explanation is simpler?

Comment: In terms of Occam's Razor, the principle that the simplest explanation is often the best, it's important to remember that 'simplest' doesn't mean 'most minimal.' It means the explanation that makes the fewest assumptions while still accounting for all the facts. In that sense, the existence of other minds is a far simpler—and more useful—hypothesis than solipsism.

Comment: Because solipsism fails to account for the complexity and richness of our experiences. If we are the only conscious entities, how do we account for the diversity and unpredictability of the world around us? Are we to believe that we are dreaming up every blade of grass, every book we read, every conversation we have?

In contrast, the idea that other minds exist—while it may be more 'complex' in that it posits the existence of billions of individual consciousnesses—actually offers more explanatory power.

Comment: But the existence of other minds is a simpler explanation than solipsism because it offers a single mechanism to explain my behavior and the behavior of other people. The question is how to determine what type of simplicity we should believe.

Comment: the question of 'what type of simplicity we should believe' is misguided. We should not seek out simplicity for simplicity's sake, but rather strive for understanding and knowledge, no matter how complex or uncomfortable it might be

Comment: Also the very premise of your question, 'what type we should believe', is fundamentally flawed. It suggests that belief is a matter of choice, a picking and choosing of concepts based on their simplicity, complexity, or appeal. This is a gross misunderstanding of the nature of belief and knowledge.

Belief isn't a smorgasbord from which we select the most palatable options. It isn't a supermarket where we choose what appeals to us most. Rather, belief should be compelled by evidence. Otherwise it's like religious brainwashing and dogmas

Comment: Then explain why solipsism loses if it has fewer entities? Solipsism can easily explain all phenomena by adding many different assumptions, just like any skeptical model.

Answer (score 0):

In my perspective, anchored in a neurobiological understanding of the world, the 'simplest' explanation would be the one that aligns most closely with what we know about how the brain works. Ontological simplicity and explanatory simplicity aren't always at odds. A theory that posits fewer entities, if those entities are consistent with neurobiological data, may provide a more unified explanation for a range of phenomena.

Determining 'simplicity' isn't an arbitrary decision made by a single person. It's a collective process in the scientific and philosophical community, grounded in evidence. The 'simplest' explanation will be the one that best fits the data, explains the most phenomena, and makes the fewest unsupported assumptions.

Remember, Occam's Razor is a heuristic, not an absolute rule. Simplicity is one among many factors in theory choice. Others include empirical accuracy, coherence with other accepted theories, and explanatory breadth and depth. So, simplicity is a guide, but it doesn't always dictate the best theory.

Comment: How about solipsism? Solipsism has fewer essences but more explanation. The existence of other minds has fewer explanations but more essences. Which explanation is simpler? Does the fact that there is only one conscious mind in solipsism make it simpler?

Comment: @Johnny5454 What does solipsism explain? It is entirely empty intellectually.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ad-hoc aesthetic judgment that powers a rule of thumb, not a reliable heuristic. The simplicity rule is a very crude approximation of doing real statistics with real measurements. As you suggest, you can always subdivide contingent entities or extend contingent explanations farther down the causal chain if you start counting like the counted number means something. If we were doing stats, this wouldn't do anything - we'd just be replacing numbers with expressions that come out to the same number.

Comment: How about solipsism? Solipsism has fewer essences but more explanation. The existence of other minds has fewer explanations but more essences. Which explanation is simpler? Does the fact that there is only one conscious mind in solipsism make it simpler?

Comment: @Johnny5454 Solipsism isn't a hypothesis because it predicts no measurements which not-solipsism doesn't predict. So in addition to "who cares, it's subjective anyway", I would suggest that it's also irrelevant to IBE, and that questions about the merits of solipsism as a hypothesis don't mean anything.

Comment: But to reject solipsism, it is necessary to indicate why it is worse. The explanation of solipsism includes fewer entities (only one conscious mind), but more explanations (one mechanism is responsible for my behavior, and another mechanism is responsible for the behavior of other people) Why is this simplicity of solipsism not the best explanation for other people's behavior?

Comment: Explanatory power also depends on simplicity. Otherwise, we could make many arbitrary assumptions that are possible and cannot be tested empirically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take relative probabilities into account. A theory which explains a phenomenon in terms of 50 facts which are known to be true can more plausible than an explanation based on only one assumption which has a probability less than 1.

If you ask me how my car works, I can provide an explanation which involves a large number of entities, such as a crankshaft, pistons, fuel injectors, air filter, etc etc, or I can say a magic fairy makes it go. The second explanation has far fewer entities but is not better.